# Obtener el min de un campo

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un problema, estoy intentando obtener el minimo de un campos, cuanto utilizo MIN() me muestra el numero más pequeño, por ejemplo: mi campo se llama carne y tiene como dato 10,4,6,2,3 y cuando hago la consulta me arroja "2", porque es el más pequeño.

Pero no requiero eso lo que requiero es por ejemplo, sum esos datos y del total sacar un min, no se como explicarme, por ejemplo: dato 10,4,6,2,3 si utilizo SUM(dato) me arrojara "25", ahora mi duda es como sacar el MIN de 25, no se si sea con AVG o MIN pero no me dan el resultado esperado.

```
SELECT dias, fechas, SUM(carne_arabe) FROM base WHERE dias LIKE '%" .$dia. "%' 
                                                AND mes LIKE '%".$mes."%' 
                                                AND anio LIKE '%".$anio."%'
                                                AND categoria IN('CALDOS','COMPLEMENTOS','EMPAQUES','ENTRADAS','ESPECIALIDADES','EXTRAS','KILO','PROMO','TACOS')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto obtengo mi resultado total, pero aun no doy como obtener el MIN de ese total.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ACTUALIZADO:
Ya logre sacar el total de este resultado y agrupar como lo quiero, ahora mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para sacar el minimo de ese resultado...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En php tengo asi mi query pero solo me muestra una información

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por responder, pues es lo que no entiendo como sacarlo, por ejemplo obtengo mi resultado $fila['arabe'] luego hago esto $minArabe = MIN($fila['arabe']), no se si estoy bien o como debo de hacerlo

Comment: @JorgeGarduza si quieres sacar el mínimo de un campo, creo que si esta bien, pero si deseas sacar el mínimo de todos los campos, la cosa cambia

Comment: Exacto, además de que la información de este campo va creciendo diariamente, ahorita por ejemplo tengo 54,388 datos dentro de este campo, obvio en algunos estan en ceros pero esos los omito..

Comment: Pon un ejemplo gráfico, para entenderte mejor

Comment: @Japv Listo ya la subí

Comment: Me refería a que pusieras una imagen de ejemplo con los datos y otra que tenga el resultado esperado, algo así como un antes y un después

Comment: Lo que no entiendo eso del min del total

Comment: Ok, lo tengo en un excel, pero lo estoy tratando de automatizar, pongo el ejemplo del excel

Comment: A ver, tu tienes varios tipos de carne, tu lo que quieres es hallar el total por cada tipo de carne y de todos esos sub totales sacar el menor de todos?

Comment: no entiendo como podes tener el minimo de algo, cuando el minimo de un solo numero es si mismo.. el minimo de que cosa queres?

Comment: y decime que no hiciste una base de datos, donde las fechas estan partidas en muchos campos... por favor decime que no es asi....

Comment: @Japv, así es lo que necesito, sacar el min del total del campo, como se ve en el excel, pues en el excel se usa la funcion MIN y se selecciona un rango de campos.

Comment: @gbianchi, desafortunadamente tuve que partir las fechas en tres campos porque en el sistema que genero ese reporte, así lo arroja, lo siento...

Comment: Que sistema usas para hacer el reporte que tienes q separar la fecha de esa forma?

Comment: JoinPoster es un crm @Japv

Comment: Y aca es lo mismo.. si tenes un rango de fechas, el min al sacar la fecha del group by, sera de ese rango de fechas... y es muy raro lo que contas de eso que tengas que separar las fechas.. te quiero ver cuando necesites hacer algo que sea del ultimo año nada mas.. el where es espantoso...

Comment: Agrega `MIN(carne_arabe)` al `SELECT`

Comment: @mr-dev ya lo realicé así pero me saca de todo el campo, mira lo que hice para agrupar con sum fue group by fechas y así me arroja solamente los cuatro o cinco días que tenga el mes por ejemplo 5 lunes y ahí me separa los campos por cada lunes pero de ahí ya no se como sacar el min y max de esas cantidades

Comment: Tu código debe ir como texto